# How to send a GET request and read the response back in Objective C iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, nsurlrequest, nsjsonserialization

This is my code. I am sending a Get request to a link and trying to read the response back.
I get this parse error

```
 Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}
```

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
  if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
   } else {
       NSError *parseError = nil;
       NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
         options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&parseError];
       if (parseError) {
         NSLog(@"%@", parseError);
       }
```

Comment: This error means the received data is not valid JSON, it's most likely the HTML text of a server error message. Create a string from `data` and `NSLog` it.

Comment: NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; This code helped me log it now. I guess NSJSONSerialization wouldn't work on this. This is how the response looked like
<script>
var value = confirm("Click Ok to confirm, cancel to dispute")
console.log(value)
</script>
<h1>Hello .</h1>

Comment: As I said this is HTML not JSON. I guess there is something wrong with the sent request.

Comment: Question: "Is  the URL" a real Web Service that can send back JSON according to some specificities (param, auth, etc.?) at all? If not, then it won't work. It's like asking for a steack at the bakery. Of course they sell food (internet content), but not meat ("JSON"), but have plenty of breads ("html", "javascript", etc.).

Comment: Oh okay awesome explanation Larme. I get your analogy. It is a real url. A google app engine endpoint. I think I know what needs to be done now. It has to be configured to be a json to use it as a json right. –